# Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String

Tags: string, flash, actionscript, scene

There is an object called `bird`. I want to go to a new scene `2, 1`  after that bird reaches location of `bird.y = -575`.

However, when debugging the code, I got

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 44  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String.
```

How to fix it?

**Code**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stop();

var birdVelocity:int = 0;
var stageGravity:int = 2;

function BirdFall(event:Event):void
{
    bird.y = bird.y + birdVelocity;
    birdVelocity = birdVelocity + stageGravity;
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, BirdFall);

function FlyBird(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    birdVelocity = -10;
    bird.gotoAndStop(2);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, FlyBird);

if (bird.y == 575) {
    gotoAndPlay("Scene 2", 1)
}
```

Comment: What is the code on line 44?

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'm not a Flash developer, but from [this reference page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000566.html), your code seems to be correct... except there is no `;` (semicolon) on that line. Is that a possible cause?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. It won't be useful since I'm not a Flash developer. Sorry, better wait for other answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly have no idea why it's set up like this as the gotoAndPlay function on Adobe's actual page says you're supposed to put where you want to go first and the frame second, but it's swapped for some unknown reason, so you're actually supposed to write it as:

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
```

I had the same problem and found out you're supposed to have the frame first and it worked for me.